# Escribir en un fichero Python

Tags: python, ubuntu

Estoy intentando configurar un archivo Cron desde python.
Me han pedido que el archivo se tiene que crear en la ruta /etc/cron.d/
Hasta aquí todo bien, dejo mi código.

```
from subprocess import PIPE, Popen

def programar_accion(request):
  commandDB3 = 'sudo touch /etc/cron.d/nombrefile'
  Popen(commandDB3, shell=True, stdout=PIPE)
```

Esto después de añadir `carmen ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL`   al final del archivo después de ejecutar `sudo visudo` en la terminal.

Como podéis ver, se crea el archivo sin problemas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema viene cuando intento introducir contenido en ese archivo, he probado con:

```
def programar_accion(request, id):

  commandDB3 = 'sudo touch /etc/cron.d/nombrefile'

  Popen(commandDB3, shell=True, stdout=PIPE)
  with open('/etc/cron.d/nombrefile', 'w+') as f:
    f.write("0 0 * * * mkdir ~/Escritorio/prueba_eje")
```

El problema es que esto me da un error de permisos, adjunto error.

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/etc/cron.d/nombrefile'
```

Estoy bastante perdida al respecto, no se si primero tengo que crear un archivo, escribir en el y luego llevarlo a la ruta de /etc/cron.d/.

Espero que podáis ayudarme, Gracias!!

Comment: Estás ejecutando el archivo de python como sudo también? Si no es así, puede ser que el error derive de ahí.

Comment: No exactamente, esta función es una vista de Django.

Comment: Hay una carpeta en el mismo directorio que el archivo a abrir llamada "nombrefile"? Por ejemplo, en el directorio /etc/cron.d existe una carpeta llamada nombrefile y un archivo llamado nombrefile al mismo tiempo? Si este es el caso, es posible que el open esté tratando de abrir la carpeta como si fuera texto plano.

Comment: No, el archivo que se crea es porque le he creado yo en la función. @DanteS.

Comment: Lo se. Pero estaba esa posibilidad de todos modos.

Comment: Ya que sabes usar `subprocess` te puedes crear un proceso que ejecute una terminal de Python desde `root` para así poder escribir.

Answer (score 0):

El error está en que `/etc/cron.d/` y sus archivos son propiedad de `root`:

```
candid@gear:~/PycharmProjects/pandas$ ls /etc/cron.d -l
total 8
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 285 Jul 16  2019 anacron
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 201 Feb 14  2020 e2scrub_all
```

Los archivos tienen permiso de lectura para cualquiera, pero no grabación/ejecución. El problema es que el script ejecuta bajo una cuenta que no es `root` ni tiene derecho sobre ese directorio, por lo que no puede agregar, modificar o eliminar archivos.

Existe la opción de administrar un crontab particular al usuario/cuenta (usando `crontab -e`), pero no resuelve el problema, pues ese archivo de configuración (`/var/spool/cron/crontabs/usuario`) tampoco es editable por un programa del usuario (solo con `crontab`).

**Solución**

Lo más sano es:

1. Generar los archivos cron en un directorio común y corriente, sobre el cual tengas permisos.
2. Configurar un script bash (propiedad de `root`) que revise el directorio anterior y copie a `/etc/cron.d/` los archivos nuevos/actualizados (puedes usar `rsync` para resolver esa parte).